# Change the data of a QAbstractTableModel programatically

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt4

I need to change the data stored in an instance of `QAbstractTableModel`, and below is my attempt which runs but does nothing.

```
class index(QtCore.QModelIndex):
    def __init__(self, row_, col_):
        QtCore.QModelIndex.__init__(self)
        self.r = row_
        self.c = col_

    def column(self):
        return self.c

    def row(self):
        return self.r
```

And I use this in a loop to set a column with a value:

```
val = self.ui.doubleSpinBox.value()
for i in range(self.links_model.rowCount()):
    self.links_model.setData(index(i, 4), val, QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole)
```

In this code
    `self.links_model`   is an instance of `QAbstractTableModel`

So, regardless of the code I have posted, how do I change the values of an instance of `QAbstractTableModel` in python?

Comment: How do you subclass `QAbstractTableModel` ? Does the 4th column always have to be the value of the spin box ? You shouldn't have to subclass `QModelIndex`

Answer (score 0):

So, digging in the Python API (...) I found how to do it:

```
val = self.ui.doubleSpinBox.value() # some value to set
for i in range(self.links_model.rowCount()):
    item = QtGui.QStandardItem()
    item.setData(val, QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole)
    self.links_model.setItem(i, 4, item) # i-> row, 4-> column
```